# How to add multiple users in Multi-user People Picker field (Person or Group Field)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I want to add multiple users in multi-picker person field in SharePoint list. I tried below code but always getting an error that:

> New-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
$ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Securedpw = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Securedpw)
$web = $ClientContext.Web 
$list= $web.lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$ClientContext.Load($list)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
$ListItemCreationInformation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$ListItem= $list.AddItem($ListItemCreationInformation)

$UserAccounts="domain\arzoo; domain\ashwin"
$UserAccountsColl = $UserAccounts -split ';'
$UserCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection
foreach($UserAccount in $UserAccountsColl)
{    
   #Get the User
    $User=$web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)

    #Add to collection
    $UserFieldValue = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($Web, $User.ID, $User.LoginName)
    $UserCollection.Add($UserFieldValue)
}

#update the Multiple value Person or Group field
$ListItem[$FieldName] = $UserCollection
$ListItem.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Load SharePoint CSOM assemblies in beginning:

```
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")
```

And try to initialize `$UserCollection` as below in your code:

```
$UserCollection = @()
foreach($UserAccount in $UserAccountsColl)
{    
   #Get the User
    $User=$web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)
    $spuserValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
    $spuserValue.LookupId = $User.id  
    $UserCollection += $spuserValue
}
$userValueCollection = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]]$UserCollection 

#update the Multiple value Person or Group field
$ListItem[$FieldName] = $userValueCollection
$ListItem.Update()
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried to initialize $UserCollection and loaded relevant path also still getting the same error @dikesh gandhi

Comment: Hello Dikesh. Your added .dlls do not deliver the `SPFieldUserValueCollection`. Therefore, you would need to add the `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`.

Comment: Thanks @SteffPoint for drawing my attention. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I have made the experience, that when writing multiple users to a person field (multi = true) in a document library (SP2013 on prem), only the first person is written into the SP- field. Do you have any idea, what could be the issue? My script is pretty much the same as yours - see here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272870/write-multiple-people-in-multi-value-person-field-using-powershell-csom